# How java package version is changing when have only deprecated methods

Tags: java, osgi, version, deprecated, specifications

I am thinking of the best way to manage package versioning in our project when have @deprecated annotation of some methods. We are using the maven-bundle-plugin, which either takes a package version from a packageinfo file or if there are no files, from the bundle-version.

We follow this convention about packages: ("X.Y.Z") where Z is growing when there is bug fix, Y is growing when there is new feature and X is growing when there is no compatibility.

So lets say we have package P with version ("1.0.0"). In P there is two classes Foo and Bar. If we have two methods in Foo - A() and B() and we have deprecated method A() and this are all changes in the hole package. How the package version is changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll refer to these version segments by their proper OSGi names: Major (your X), Minor (Y) and Micro (Z):

- Major should be incremented when there is a breaking change that affects all users of the API;
- Minor should be incremented when there is a new feature, which does not break consumers but it may break providers since they cannot automatically provide the new feature;
- Micro should be incremented for any other change that does not cause any backwards compatibility issues.

Clearly adding `@Deprecated` to a method does not change the compatibility for either consumers or providers. Therefore this is a Micro change (in your example you should increment "Z"). It is at most a documentation change for the API.